Error when trying anchor build
I have been running to a parse error - when running anchor build, I was able to solve this by downloading a previous version of cargo, solana and rust, for some reason the current cargo file as a sync/compatible error when trying to be read by the terminal.
The error asks if there is a newer version of cargo and/or needs to be updated, which when uninstalling and redownloading the versions, I finally found that through different variations of the versions it would finally recongize the path to run anchor build. Posting for anyone else trying to experiment.
